# Why did the pointer p terminate when it met 0?

Tags: c++, c

I do not understand why the pointer was terminated when it met 0 instead of reaching the end of this int array. Thank you for your explanation! It really helps the beginners like me.

---

```
int *p,b;
int a[9]={1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,0};
p=a;
while((b=*p++)) printf("%d %d\n",b,*p);
printf("*p=%d\n", *p);
```

---

```
Output:
1 2
2 3
3 0 
*p = 1
```

Comment: Worth noting that if there were no zeros in the list, then you'd get undefined behavior as you'd run off the end and try to dereference memory you don't own

Comment: Did you try running this in a debugger, and seeing the reason, yourself?

Comment: There is no char* in this problem. I am a little bit lost about what you mean.@SilvioMayolo

Comment: `while((b=*p++)) ` loops until it encounters a zero.

Answer (score 3):

It is because `while` loop ends when the condition becomes false. Zero is considered as false, so it stops at zero.

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally got it now.